# How to solve "Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to pass `Array[List]` called `alarm_stat` as the argument of UDF function. This is the content of `alarm_stat`:

```
alarm_stat_ds: [
                Row(
                    f_id=2, 
                    type='activity', 
                    qty=1, 
                    number_hosts=1
                   )
               ]
```

My code:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('prob', StringType()), StructField('level', StringType())
])

get_alert_udf = func.udf(ah.get_alert, schema)

df = df \
    .withColumn("val", func.when(func.col("is_inside") == 1,
                                 get_alert_udf(
                                               func.col("id"),
                                               alarm_stat
                                              ))
                            .otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("0"),func.lit("0")).cast(schema))
```

However I get the following error message:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```